# Nothing renders in the ASP.MVC 3 View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my ASP.NET MVC project, I have this code in a view:

```
[...]

<%if(item.IsActive)
{
    Html.ActionLink("Deactivate", "ChangeVisibility", new { id = item.Id, val = false }, new { @class = "activate-manipulate-news" });
}
else
{
    Html.ActionLink("Activate", "ChangeVisibility", new { id = item.Id, val = true }, new { @class = "activate-manipulate-news" });
}
%>
```

I'm trying to figure out, why that code nothing renders in the output. The controller and the `ChangeVisibility` is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if else sytax should be something like below.

```
<% if (true) { %>
<%= "Condition met" + ... %>
<% } 
else { %>
<%= "condition not met" %>
<% } %
```

I never worked on this syntax, but I googled for if else syntax in asp.net mvc and found this link which explains the syntax difference between MVC2 and MVC3 razon syntax. http://www.csharpcity.com/ifelse-statements-in-mvc3-with-razor/

Comment: That's poor usage of the Razor syntax.

Answer (score 1):

A single @ sign will suffice, like this:

```
@if(item.IsActive)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Deactivate", "ChangeVisibility", new { id = item.Id, val = false }, new { @class = "activate-manipulate-news" });
}
else
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Activate", "ChangeVisibility", new { id = item.Id, val = true }, new { @class = "activate-manipulate-news" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is item in this ??

If you are passing some model from contoller to view, it should be accessed via `Model.item` or if item is something in the ViewBag or ViewdData dictionary then you need to use `ViewBag.item`

Comment: item is a class object from the List

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `Html.ActionLink()` but you are not writing it's result to the document.

```
<% if (item.IsActive) { %>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Deactivate", "ChangeVisibility", new { id = item.Id, val = false }, new { @class = "activate-manipulate-news" }); %>
<% } else { %>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Activate", "ChangeVisibility", new { id = item.Id, val = true }, new { @class = "activate-manipulate-news" }); %>
<% } %>
```